# FireStore getDocuments() Function running extremely slow when a query is searched for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore

**Background**

I am using Firebase Firestore to retrieve English words data using the `getDocuments()` function. Here is the Data Model for the retrieved data.

```
struct WordModel: Codable {

    let id: String
    let number: Int
    var partOfSpeech: [String]?
    var ipa: [String?]
    var audio: [String?]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case number
        case partOfSpeech
        case ipa
        case audio
    }
}
```

The query is a word or sentence that is broken into an array of arrays of words, where each array of words, has a chunk size of at most 10. I then use the `.whereField("id", in: wordChunk)` to query for those words. wordChunk is an array of at most 10 words. Here is the function that runs the query and returns the results:

```
    func readEnglishDocumentByWord(words: [String], completion: @escaping(_ result: [WordModel?]) -> Void) {

        var results = [WordModel?]()
        var finalResult = [WordModel?]()
        var data: WordModel?
        let lowerCaseWords = words.map { $0.lowercased() }
        let wordChunks = lowerCaseWords.chunked(into: 10)

        start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() //start timer
        for wordChunk in wordChunks {

            let docRefs = db.collection(K.FBConstants.dictionaryCollectionName).whereField("id", in: wordChunk)

            docRefs.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
                self.first = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() // first time check
                print("First: \(self.first! - self.start!)")
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    completion(finalResult)
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        do {
                            data = try document.data(as: WordModel.self)
                            results.append(data)
                        } catch {
                            results.append(nil)
                        }
                    }
                    for word in words {
                        let tempWordModel = results.filter { $0?.id == word.lowercased() }

                        if tempWordModel.count == 0 {finalResult.append(nil)}
                        else {finalResult.append(tempWordModel[0])}
                    }
                }
                completion(finalResult)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

Say I search the sentence: "today will be a good day"

This means that `wordChunk = [today, will, be, a, good, day]`

If this sentence has never been searched before, the query will literally take **30s**. This number is retrieved from `print("First: \(self.first! - self.start!)")`.
If I search this same thing again, it will take at most **1s**. This occurs with any search no matter how large or small. I did some research and I found some people mentioning something about cloud function cold start time, as well as others having similar issues, but I was unable to find a quality solution for solving this problem. I tried disabling persistence `settings.isPersistenceEnabled = true` but that did not work. Is there a solution? Am I implementing something incorrectly or is it an issue with Firestore. Any help or advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Cloud Functions (unless you are using a function here that we can't see).  You might want to read: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/08/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow.html

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the response. I actually did read that already as well, but it didn't seem like anything in it made sense as far as making first-time reading times as long as 30 seconds. What's throwing me off is that after being searched once, it no longer takes the 30 seconds. Maybe it has to do with caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just pulling each of the documents out individually using `getDocument()` instead of using the where clause, and using a Dispatch group to tell me when all the queries finished.

```
    func readEnglishDocumentByWord(words: [String], completion: @escaping(_ result: [WordModel?]) -> Void) {

        var results = [WordModel?]()
        var finalResults = [WordModel?]()
        let lowerCaseWords = words.map { $0.lowercased() }
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() //start timer
        for word in lowerCaseWords {

            let docRef = db.collection(K.FBConstants.dictionaryCollectionName).document(word)
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                self.first = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() // first time check
                print("First: \(self.first! - self.start!)")

                let result = Result {
                    try document.flatMap {
                        try $0.data(as: WordModel.self)
                    }
                }
                switch result {
                case .success(let wordModel):
                    if let wordModel = wordModel {
                        results.append(wordModel)
                    } else {
                        results.append(nil)
                        print("Document does not exist")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    results.append(nil)
                    print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            for word in words {
                let temp = results.filter{$0?.id == word.lowercased()}
                if temp.count == 0 {finalResults.append(nil)}
                else {
                    finalResults.append(temp[0])
                }

            }
            completion(finalResults)
            print("Finished with results: \(results.count)")
        }
    }
```